# Error in .Call("dplyr_rbind_list__impl", PACKAGE = "dplyr", dots)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to run an R script using a batch file. Each time i run the batch file it throws me an error:

```
Error in .Call("dplyr_rbind_list__impl", PACKAGE = "dplyr", dots)
```

When i run the sessionInfo it ives me the following:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plyr_1.8.4           stringr_1.2.0        jsonlite_1.1         httr_1.2.1           reshape2_1.4.3      
 [6] RODBC_1.3-14         dtplyr_0.0.1         dplyr_0.5.0          data.table_1.10.4-3  ROracle_1.3-1       
[11] DBI_0.7              lubridate_1.7.2      RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0 RevoUtils_10.0.2     RevoMods_10.0.0     
[16] MicrosoftML_1.0.0    mrsdeploy_1.0        RevoScaleR_9.0.1     lattice_0.20-34      rpart_4.1-10        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.15           rstudioapi_0.7         CompatibilityAPI_1.1.0 magrittr_1.5           R6_2.2.0              
 [6] rlang_0.4.1.9000       foreach_1.4.3          tools_3.3.2            grid_3.3.2             cli_1.0.0             
[11] iterators_1.0.8        lazyeval_0.2.1         yaml_2.1.16            assertthat_0.2.0       mrupdate_1.0.0        
[16] tibble_1.4.2           crayon_1.3.4           codetools_0.2-15       curl_2.2               stringi_1.1.6         
[21] pillar_1.1.0
```

when i use rbind_list it throws a warning message:

```
Warning message:
`rbind_list()` is deprecated. Please use `bind_rows()` instead.
```

This is halting my batch process. What is it that i am missing out on?
Also when i manually run the R script using bind_rows, the code works. Is this a R version/dplyr version issue?

Comment: Looks like your R version is old as well as dplyr

Comment: @akrun For my batch file however i use the latest version: "C:\R-3.4.3\bin\Rscript.exe" "MyFile.R" 
This is causing the error

Comment: @lea: Your R version is 2 years old. Latest R version is `3.6.1`. `v3.6.2` will be released on 12/12/2019. Latest `dplyr` version is 0.8.3.